# Tokenising words in a dictionary Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I have json file where I import data into python.

I have an agentId field and an agentText field in JSON

Sample json:

```
{
"messages": 
[
    {"agentId": "1", "agentText": "I Love Python"},
    {"agentId": "2", "agentText": "but cant seem to get my head around it"},
    {"agentId": "3", "agentText": "what are the alternatives?"}
]
}
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary/key pair value with agentIds and the AgentText fields by doing the following:

When I do this, the key value pairs work fine:

```
import json

with open('20190626-101200-text-messages2.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for message in data['messages']:
        agentIdandText = {message['agentId']: [message['agentText']]}
        print(agentIdandText)
```

and the output I get this:

```
{'1': ['I love python']}
{'2': ["but cant seem to get my head around it"]}
{'3': ['what are the alternatives?']}
```

but as soon as I try to tokenise the words(below), I start hitting errors

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
varToken = TweetTokenizer()

import json

with open('20190626-101200-text-messages2.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for message in data['messages']:
        agentIdandText = {message['agentId']: varToken.tokenize([message['agentText']])}
        print(agentIdandText)
```

Partial error message (edited in from comments):

```
return ENT_RE.sub(_convert_entity, _str_to_unicode(text, encoding)) 
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

So what I'm expecting is this:

```
{
'1': ['I', 'love', 'python'],
'2': ['but', 'cant', 'seem', 'to', 'get', 'my', 'head', 'around', 'it'],
'3': ['what', 'are', 'the', 'alternatives?']
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: so with your code , what output you are getting ?

Comment: i get `return ENT_RE.sub(_convert_entity, _str_to_unicode(text, encoding))
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: @dragonfury2 Please add the full error message in the question.

Comment: do convert `agentIdandText = {message['agentId']: varToken.tokenize([message['agentText']])}` to `agentIdandText = {message['agentId']: varToken.tokenize(message['agentText'])}`

Comment: Thanks to all responses, they all work in different ways.

Comment: @dragonfury2: prashat rana and Kenstars identify your real issue, which is you are trying to pass a list to an api that expects a string.  More specifically `[message['agentText']]` is a list of a single string.  Doing `varToken.tokenize([message['agentText']])` passes a list to `varToken.Tokenize()`.  If you get rid of the extra brackets around `message['agentText']` you are then passing a bare string (like so `varToken.tokenize(message['agentText'])`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this change solve your problem,
I think you will have to pass string to the tokenize function.

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
varToken = TweetTokenizer()
import json
with open('20190626-101200-text-messages2.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
output_data = {}
for message in data['messages']:
    agentIdandText = {message['agentId']: varToken.tokenize(message['agentText'])}
    #print(agentIdandText)
    output_data.update(agentIdandText)
print (output_data)
```

Edit:
Added output_data variable to showcase all the keys in one dictionary.

Comment: This is almost what im after, except it needs to be in this format: 
`{
'1': ['I', 'love', 'python'],
'2': ['but', 'cant', 'seem', 'to', 'get', 'my', 'head', 'around', 'it'],
'3': ['what', 'are', 'the', 'alternatives?']
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split()` with dictionary comprehension:

```
agentIdandText = {d['agentId']: d['agentText'].split() for d in data["messages"]}
```

Output:

```
{
'1': ['I', 'Love', 'Python'], 
'2': ['but', 'cant', 'seem', 'to', 'get', 'my', 'head', 'around', 'it'], 
'3': ['what', 'are', 'the', 'alternatives?']
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to use the `TweetTokenizer` from `nltk.tokenize`. The root error in the OP's code was passing a list to a function that expected a string.

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative approach without depending on external package. Since when did providing a different approach (possibly better) than OP to achieve the same output result in a downvote?

Comment: `TweetTokenizer` doesn't do the same thing as `str.split`.  His example output is actually incorrect in the last instance in that the question mark gets split by the tokenizer, which he missed because he didn't actually call it correctly.  `str.split` *might* be what he wants, but the best way to say that is something like "It looks like all you want is to split the string on whitespace, if so `str.split()` has you covered."  That leaves room for ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = {
    "messages": 
    [
        {"agentId": "1", "agentText": "I Love Python"},
        {"agentId": "2", "agentText": "but cant seem to get my head around it"},
        {"agentId": "3", "agentText": "what are the alternatives?"}
    ]
}


result = [ {e['agentId']:e['agentText'].split()} for e in temp['messages']]

for e in result:
    print(e)

#result 
{'1': ['I', 'Love', 'Python']}
{'2': ['but', 'cant', 'seem', 'to', 'get', 'my', 'head', 'around', 'it']}
{'3': ['what', 'are', 'the', 'alternatives?']}
```

you should check this out [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Comment: The OP wants to use the `TweetTokenizer` from `nltk.tokenize`. The root error in the OP's code was passing a list to a function that expected a string.

Comment: yep I got it. :P